# Foreign key constraint fails in transaction

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, yii, innodb

I'm developing a web-based application with PHP/MySQL + Yii Framework. The problem occurs as a constraint check error in a transaction.

I have the following tables:

### User

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `User` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creation_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_login_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `level` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=40 ;
```

### CandidateInfo

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CandidateInfo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `candidate_status_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `date_of_birth` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `home_phone` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile_phone` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creation_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `rating` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `location` varchar(100)DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_candidateinfo_user` (`id`),
  KEY `FK_candidateinfo_candidatestatus` (`candidate_status_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=26 ;
```

Basically I'm trying to add a new row to **User** table, and then use the insert id to add a new row to the **CandidateInfo** table (user_id column)

The php code is as

```
$transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
try {
    $user->save();
    $candidate->setAttribute('user_id', $user->id);
    $candidate->save();
    $transaction->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $transaction->rollBack();
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

The error is:

```
 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`origo`.`CandidateInfo`, CONSTRAINT `FK_candidateinfo_user` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `User` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION). The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `CandidateInfo` (`gender`, `rating`, `name`, `surname`, `email`, `date_of_birth`, `home_phone`, `mobile_phone`, `user_id`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3, :yp4, :yp5, :yp6, :yp7, :yp8)
```

When i check the mysql query logs, i see that it takes the right user_id for the INSERT statement for CandidateInfo table. But fails with the above error. From my understanding, it is supposed to work, but may be i am mistaken and this is not the way transactions are meant to work.

Both tables are InnoDB.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** 
Sorry forgot to paste the FK relations.

```
ALTER TABLE `CandidateInfo`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_candidateinfo_candidatestatus` FOREIGN KEY (`candidate_status_id`) REFERENCES `CandidateStatus` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_candidateinfo_user` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `User` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Comment: neither of your table samples have any foreign keys, plus you've got a duplicated key on the `id` field in candidate info. just naming a key `FK_whatever` doesn't make it a foreign key - you've just got regular keys.

Comment: obviously forgot to include them in the DDL, sorry.

Comment: Ok, you've got two keys, and it looks like you're setting the user_id one... so where are you putting in the value for candidate status?

Comment: It is a column with default NULL. I am not setting any value for it in the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE `CandidateInfo`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_candidateinfo_candidatestatus` FOREIGN KEY (`candidate_status_id`) REFERENCES `CandidateStatus` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_candidateinfo_user` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `User` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

should be

```
ALTER TABLE `CandidateInfo`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_candidateinfo_candidatestatus` FOREIGN KEY (`candidate_status_id`) REFERENCES `CandidateStatus` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_candidateinfo_user` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `User` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

you've got id references id in yours.

Answer (score 3):

Your error stack:

> > SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`origo`.`CandidateInfo`, CONSTRAINT `FK_candidateinfo_user` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `User` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION).
> >
> > The SQL statement executed was:

```
INSERT INTO `CandidateInfo`
( `gender`, `rating`, `name`, `surname`, `email`, 
  `date_of_birth`, `home_phone`, `mobile_phone`, `user_id`
)
VALUES ( :yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3, :yp4, :yp5, :yp6, :yp7, :yp8 )
```

Your `CandidateInfo` table defines `id` field as `auto_increment` primary key field and a foreign key as well.
And your `insert` statement does not include `id`, read from its parent `user` table.
And hence on insert a *new* `id` value is generated for `candidateinfo` table and applied.
Which intern failed as it did not match any of the primary key `id` value of the parent `user` table.

And hence is the error.

**Note**:
In a child table if your are referring a pk field of a master as a foreign key field,
you should not apply `auto_increment` for it but just refer.

---

And looking closely the `candidateinfo` structure, I feel that you might want to map `use_id` to `user.id` field. Making that change, with proper foreign key definition used, would resolve your problem.

Comment: ya, my bad. Obviously I overlooked while writing the table definition. The user_id (not id) column is supposed to reference the id of User table.